# Advance mode is missing on Play store developer console

Tags: android, google-play

In new UI on play store developer console **APK tab** has been removed. And its being replaced by **Apk Release**

First time i am trying to upload the apk based on **cpu architecture**, but all the article showing using Advance Mode in APK tab.

But in new UI that option in not there.

**How to upload multiple apk based on CPU architecture in new UI**

Comment: Better try contacting support.

Comment: It's not necessary, the flow is simpler now. My answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In new Play store developer console if you want to add multiple APK than you must have to use same package name and same keystore key but version is change.

Now when you publish app than first upload Apk e.g mobile_release and rollout for production,after when you upload another apk than you should Choose option **RETAIN** which servered previous APK also with current APK.

So in my application i have given support of Android Wear 2.0 so i had used same way which i have described above.and both my signAPK Mobile APK and Wear APK are work fine

Comment: Ya i chat with support team said same to me.

Comment: Can I generate multiple apk using split abi in gradle? and generated file upload on play store. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For a new release you can simply add one or more APKs as needed, clicking on "Upoload APK".